# Redirct HTTP to HTTPS but for wildcard subdomains to HTTP only

Tags: .htaccess

I want to the following redirect

(1) Main domain (Any TO HTTPS)

```
example.com
www.example.com
http://example.com
http://www.example.com
```

TO

```
https://www.example.com
```

(2) Wildcard subdomain (Any to HTTP)

As far as you all know, using wildcard subdomain means anything could be a subdomain so i want to redirect for examples

```
reham.example.com TO http://reham.example.com
dave.example.com TO http://dave.example.com
egypt.example.com TO http://egypt.example.com
```

Also! keep in your mind to avoid `www.` to count like `subdomain`

Here is my try

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^((?!www\.)[^.]+)\.example\.com$
RewriteRule ^http://%1.example.com%{REQUEST_URI} [NE,L,R]
```

**The code problem**

It works correct but  fail with i call `www.mysite.com` it consider www. as subdomain then will redirect me to `HTTP` (`www.example.com`) meanwhile it should be redirect to `HTTPS` (`https://www.example.com`)

Comment: Maybe with `RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(reham|dave|egypt)\.example\.com$` or `RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^((?!www)[^.]+)\.example\.com$` (dot removed from www).

Comment: No `^((?!www\.)[^.]+)\.example\.com$` won't match `www.example.com`. You may have old browser cache

Comment: How about these 2 RewriteCond: `RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^([^.]+)\.example\.com$ RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.example\.com$`. First one requires a subdomain, second one rejects www specifically.

Answer (score 1):

Two RewriteCond could be chained.
First one requires a subdomain, second one rejects www specifically.

```
# require a subdomain in URL
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^([^.]+)\.example\.com$
# Do not match if subdomain is www
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.example\.com$
# L removed, do not make this rule the last
RewriteRule ^http://%1.example.com%{REQUEST_URI} [NE,R]

# example.com or www.example.com
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?example\.com$
RewriteRule ^https://www.example.com%{REQUEST_URI} [NE,L,R]
```